# GridView Textbox values invisible while selected

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

My Gridview views are showing in Inputboxes, it is working perfectly fine.

[image]

But the problem is while I am selecting any row of gridview the values did not show up, but the values are still there if i select particular textbox like in image 2, may white color overriding the values. Jow to show the values while selection? Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Changed in the the Gridmvc.css
          table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected td { background: #4888C2 !important; color: black; }
    table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected a { color: black; }
Now it is working.